# spark streaming + kafka always rebalance

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

spark streaming is consuming streaming from kafka, but when kafka add new topics ,spark applicaitons always go wrong (kafka's groupid rebalance), and spark applicaitons cant Auto-Recovery。

version:
kafka:kafka_2.11-1.0.0
spark:spark-streaming_2.11-2.4.0

Comment: Well, is your Spark code using a regex pattern to read from Kafka?